# multi-index and multi-column grouping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe with 3 levels index and 2 level columns.

```
                                       Group
                           Label       A        B       C        D
number      start          end              
1           2020-01-01  2020-12-31  -43.0    0      105.0   -37.0
            2020-12-15  2020-12-15  NaN     NaN      NaN    195.0
2           2019-01-01  2019-12-31  -35.0   80.0    -14.0   NaN
            2019-12-17  2019-12-17  NaN     NaN      NaN    141.0
            2020-01-01  2020-12-31  -15.0   45.0    -7.0    NaN
3           2020-12-17  2020-12-17  NaN     NaN      NaN    326.0
            2022-01-01  2022-12-31  NaN     50.0     NaN    NaN
            2023-12-31  2023-12-31  -25.0   NaN      NaN    NaN
            2023-01-01  2023-12-31  NaN    50.0      NaN    NaN            
            2020-12-15  2020-12-15  NaN     NaN      NaN    61.0
.............
```

I would like to group by number and start (only the year), summing values per Label:

```
                                      Group
                           Label       A        B       C        D
number      start          end              
1           2020        2020        -43.0    0      105.0   232.0
2           2019        2019        -35.0   80.0    -14.0   141
            2020        2020        -15.0   45.0    -7.0    NaN
3           2020        2020        NaN     NaN      NaN    387.0
            2022        2022        NaN     50.0     NaN    NaN
            2023        2023        -25.0   50.0     NaN    NaN    
.............
```

Please note that there is higher-level-column as well (called Group, and other higher-level-columns that I am not including to keep it simple) and other sub-columns (Label: A, B, C, D, repeated for each higher-level-column). 
how can I do this?
thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference the MultiIndex levels by name, and use `DatetimeIndex.year` to get just the year of the levels you care about. `min_count=1` gives `NaN` instead of `0` for group cells with all missing.

```
df.groupby(['number', 
            df.index.get_level_values('start').year,
            df.index.get_level_values('end').year]).sum(min_count=1)

                      A     B      C      D
number start end                           
1      2020  2020 -43.0   0.0  105.0  158.0
2      2019  2019 -35.0  80.0  -14.0  141.0
       2020  2020 -15.0  45.0   -7.0    NaN
3      2020  2020   NaN   NaN    NaN  387.0
       2022  2022   NaN  50.0    NaN    NaN
       2023  2023 -25.0  50.0    NaN    NaN
```

Comment: great, thanks! it works, but what if I have other "higher-level-columns" as mentioned after editing...Imagine I have another column called Group2 (also with A, B, C, D as sub-columns), how do I perform different operations on those? can I do something like .agg({('Group', 'A'):'sum', ('Group2','B'):'mean'}) ?

Comment: @Luca91 yes, you'd need to specify the aggregation in a dictionary like that, because AFAIK, `.agg` requires the full column key. Luckily if it's all mean for Group2 then you can create that dict programatically